# bash shell script command substitution problem - escape basefile name spaces - multiple pdf files to jpeg conversion using ghostscript

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, jpeg

This bash shell script
takes multiple .pdf file inputs using zenity and stores in an array for ghostscript .pdf to .jpeg conversion.

Problem

1. need the file path stored in array with escaped spaces to go into the gs command $i
2. need the basefile name for output filename in gs command inside for loop
3. gs command needs file names with spaces escaped.
4. unable to run the gs command error command not found on line 20.

Code:

```
#get list of selected files from Graphical Dialog
listOfFilesSelected=$(zenity --file-selection --multiple --filename "${HOME}/")
#echo $listOfFilesSelected

# Here pipe is our delimiter value
IFS="|" read -a listFiles <<< $listOfFilesSelected

#echo "File: ${listFiles[@]}"
# get length of an array
#arraylength=${#listFiles[@]}

#echo "${listFiles[0]}"
##echo $'\n'
#echo "Number of elements in the array: ${#listFiles[@]}"


 for i in "${listFiles[@]}"
     do
         echo $i
         baseFileName = $(basename '$i')
         echo $baseFileName

         gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=output%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r600 -q $i -c quit
     done
```

Output: Error

```
/home/q/Downloads/FinalAnsKey22COMPUTER SCIENCE.pdf
./zentest.sh: line 20: baseFileName: command not found

Error: /undefinedfilename in (/home/q/Downloads/FinalAnsKey22COMPUTER)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:732/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: For Ghostscript, put the filename in quotes "" since it includes a space. No idea what the baseFileName: command not found is though.

Comment: Run it through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), and fix the quoting and spacing problems it points out.

Comment: `baseFileName = $(basename '$i')` must have been `baseFileName=$(basename "$i")`. That is, no spaces around the `=`, and `$i` enclosed in double quotes (not single quotes). `$i` must be quoted with double quotes in `gs` command as well.

Comment: Show an output of `zenity --file-selection --multiple --filename "${HOME}/"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by others, you need to double-quote variables especially when
the filenames in the variable contain whitespaces.

Would you please try instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

listOfFilesSelected=$(zenity --file-selection --multiple --filename "${HOME}/")

IFS="|" read -ra listFiles <<< "$listOfFilesSelected"

for i in "${listFiles[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
    baseFileName=$(basename "$i")
    echo "$baseFileName"

    gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile="$baseFileName"%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r600 -q "$i" -c quit
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version of your script, check carefully I fixed multiple errors:

I recommend you check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net/

It is a static-analysis for shell scripts, that will greatly help you spotting errors, and usually lists you some options to fix it.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#get list of selected files from Graphical Dialog
mapfile -t listFiles < <(
  zenity --separator=$'\n' --file-selection --multiple --filename="$HOME/"
)

for filePath in "${listFiles[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "$filePath"
  baseFileName=${filePath##*/}
  printf '%s\n' "$baseFileName"

  # remove the echo if it does what you want
  echo gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=output%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r600 -q "$filePath" -c quit
done
```